# How can I resize a window that doesn't have the grabbing part on the bottom right?

Tags: macos, mac, display

I have Hulu desktop running and I want to make the window smaller, there are no lines which are usually present on windows for resizing on the bottom right corner, though. On windows I could right-click the title bar and choose size for these kind of windows, is there any way to do something similar on a Mac?

I tried pressing the green button on the top left, but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to find free softwares for this, I only found a donationware :

- [Window Wrangler](http://mindflow.dk/software/windowwrangler/)

Otherwise, you can have paid solutions :

- [Cinch](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/), which a nice and useful windows manager.
- [MondoMouse](http://www.atomicbird.com/mondomouse/)
- [Zooom/2](http://coderage-software.com/zooom/index_green/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I use [MercuryMover](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/26411/mercurymover) for move or resize windows with keyboard.

MercuryMover is a utility designed to help you keep your hands on the keyboard. Installed as a System Preferences panel, MercuryMover makes it possible to move and resize windows using just the keyboard.

[image]